# include iostream breaks uint32_t definition (C)

Tags: c, iostream, uint32-t

**Edit: Please disregard this question. I realized that I am an idiot and very nice and helpful people pointed out iostream is not a C but a C++ library.**

I am encountering a very strange problem.

I have a fully working program (about 1000 lines). I need to

```
#include <iostream>
```

When I do so typedef of uint32_t breaks.

It is defined as such

```
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017. And this is the error it gives

> \vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\cstdlib(19): error C2061: syntax
>   error: identifier 'noexcept'

and when I hover over now underlined uint32_t the following is said:

> uint32_t variable "uint32_t" is not a type name

commenting just the line

```
#include <iostream>
```

the program compiles and runs as expected.

What gives?

Side question. The reason I am using uint32_t is to guarantee that my variable is 32 bit long as I am doing a lot of bit manipulation. Would using unsigned int instead be safe?

Here is a list of everything I am including:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
```

Comment: I'm afraid `unsigned int` has no guaranteed size, just like regular `int`.

Comment: `<iostream>` is a C++ header, you can't use it in C.

Comment: woop Im an idiot. Thank you :) Was googling stuff didnt realize I was looking at C++ stuff :)

Comment: You are not supposed to include `<iostream>` in C code, since it is a C++ header and is not part of the C standard in any way.

Comment: To the person who "helpfully" added the C++ tag: that hides the problem. The title correctly points out this is a C question.

Answer (score 5):

Declaring `uint32_t` yourself is illegal afaik. Don't do that. C++ has a standard one. Use that. It's declared in `cstdint`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

If you are in `C` then the header you need to use is `stdint.h` instead:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: This is C though, not C++. Same applies?

Comment: @Duxa and just how are you using `iostream` in C ???

Comment: @Duxa and yes, it applies to C as well. Except the header is `stdint.h` instead.

Comment: Yeah I am an idiot, I didnt realize I was looking at C++ documentation. was trying to include it to read a file. Need to find a C solution. Thank you. And I was aware of stdint.h but figured it would be including too much unneeded stuff so opted to use typedef instead. Good to know that this is illegal.